# Start and stop rsync at determined hours

Tags: rsync

I want to run rsync over an adsl connection, only when i'm not using it (from midnight to the 6am).
The download of the files has to stop on 6am, and resume on midnight. There are both huge files (hundreds of GB) and little ones (a few GB).

How can i do it automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simply suggest using two crontabs

- one that starts the transfer with for instance "--partial --update" (and possibly others)
- one that kills the transfer (something like) "kill $(ps aux | grep '[r]sync' | awk '{print $2}')"

Comment: `pkill rsync`, if you have `pkill`. No need to grep then awk.

Answer (score 3):

You can run `rsync -au src dest` at midnight by scheduling a cron job. Using `-u` option will prevent copying everything again.

You can also (using a cron job at 6am) run a script to look for running rsync command and kill it using `SIGTERM`.

Answer (score 1):

using:

```
--time-limit=MINS
```

on a crontab you can finish the job after a specific time

Comment: This option is not available on CentOS linux.

Comment: @Mau This option in not available on `rsync` v3.1.2 packaged in CentOS7